# Loop through two assoc arrays and add values if needle is found to an array?

Tags: php, arrays, foreach, associative-array

I am a bit stuck with the following function. The goal is:
- Loop through an array which holds all products
- Divide products based on luxury vs no_luxury
- Another layout for available products, i have a seperate function for available products, which returns an associative array.

The main problem i have i can't parse the price value (and all other values) out of the availableProducts array. I think i need to add the corresponding $values of the $availableProducts assoc array to the $no_luxury and $luxury arrays or get associative values where =$value['productType'] from array $availableProducts

Or maybe i could merge two arrays?

Here's my simplified php code

```
<?php
$staticData = getStaticData();
$availableProducts = getAvailableProducts();

function getAllProductTypes($availableProducts, $staticData) {

    $allProductsTypes = array();
    $luxury = array();
    $no_luxury = array();

    $no_luxury_products = array('CALL','DODO','PKK','YTK','TK');
    //available products other layout with price and buy now button
    $available = array();
    //temp array for available products
    foreach($availableProducts as $value ){
        $available[] = $value['productType'];
        //HOW TO STORE an assoc array 
    }
    //get all products has no price value 
    $allProducts = getAllProducts();

     foreach ($allProducts as $value) {
        if(in_array($value["productType"], $no_luxury_products)){
            $no_luxury[] = $value;
        } else {
            $luxury[] = $value;
        }
    }
    //div no luxury

    $return = '<div id="no_luxury" style="background-color:#0099FF;">';

    foreach ($no_luxury as $value) {
        //and productType is not availabe
        if(!in_array($value['RoomType'],$available)){ 
                $return .= 'test'.$value['productType'].': '.$value['productDescr'];
        }//end not available
        else {//products ara available we have a price
                //problem i need to get the $value from the $availableProducts assoc array
                $return .= 'Price from $availableProducts assoc Array '.$value['productPrice'].': '.$value['productDescr'].' by '.$staticData['owner'];
        }
    }
    $return .= '</div>';
    //end no luxury

    //div luxury
    $return .= '<div id="luxury" >';
    foreach ($luxury as $value) {
        //and productType is not availabe
         if(!in_array($value['RoomType'],$available)){ 
                $return .= 'test'.$value['productType'].': '.$value['productDescr'];
         }//end not available
         else {//products ara available we have a price
            //problem i need to get the $value from the $availableProducts assoc array
              $return .= 'Price from $availableProducts assoc Array '.$value['productPrice'].': '.$value['productDescr'].' by '.$staticData['owner'];
         }
    }

    $return .= '</div>';
    return $return;
}
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: How are your arrays structured? In paticular availableProducts, luxury and noLuxury?

Answer (score 2):

You can use `foreach($array as $key => $value )` to also get the key while looping over an array.

Also there are `array_diff()` and `array_intersect()` which might also help you.

Comment: tx, i will look into your suggestions. At the moment i have found a workable solution by using array_merge